# Mass Transit Test Harness

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have been working on unit testing a Mass Transit Project using `InMemoryTestHarness`.

I have referred to the following github code to work with it

[`ConsumerTest_Specs.cs`](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/master/src/MassTransit.Tests/Testing/ConsumerTest_Specs.cs)

Could someone please explain what the following properties

- `Sent`
- `Published`
- `Consumed`

to the `InMemoryTestHarness _harness` object actually mean.

Although the code has a Test Method associated with each, I'ld like a bit more explanation to it.

Thanks.

Comment: These are collections of all messages that were sent, published and consumed by the harness.

Answer (score 1):

I Know the comment have the concise answer but, I think I can make it more clear by adding some adition info.

The `InMemoryTestHarness` takes the place of your m**MessageBroker** for the unit test instance, just like a **Smart Mock**. So, as a broker it has all published messages, but also keeps tracking of all messages that were transmitted.

- **Sent**: Direct commands/Messages, just like some RPC, but using the message broker as a channel. All messages that used the `Send()` method while the harness is active have a copy here.
- **Published**: Event-like Messages, following a PubSub pattern. All messages that used the `Published()` method while the harness was active have a copy here.
- **Consumed**: All messages that were consumed while the harness was active. here we have an **important consideration**:

  > Only consumers that were register in the harness will consume messages, so you have control of which consumers are active